# How can this DOM translation or merging XML/HTML be done in PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, drupal, ms-word

I have a XML file and a HTML file and would like to combine this to a new document.

For me this is the first time to do things like this as well that I'm not a PHP developer.

The result of this should become a word document...

### XML file

This file will be generated (source: drupal)

```
<professie>Manager</professie>
<gebdate>1960</gebdate>
    <project>
        <rol>Projectmanager</rol>
        <opdrachtgever>Apple</opdrachtgever>
        <result>Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsumLorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsumLorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsumLorum ipsum Lorum ipsum </result>
        <time>2012-2013</time>
    </project>

    <project>
        <rol>Teamleader</rol>
        <opdrachtgever>Google</opdrachtgever>
        <result>Lorum at google ipsum Lorum ipsumLorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsumLorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsumLorum ipsum Lorum ipsum </result>
        <time>2011-2014</time>
    </project>
```

### Template HTML file including inline css

In real this will be a exported word document to a file in the format html filtered

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Profession</td>
            <td>[professie]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date of birth</td>
            <td>[gebdate]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<project>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&gt;</td>
            <td>Rol</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>[rol]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Opdrachtgever</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>[opdrachtgever]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Resultaat</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>[result]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Datum</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>[time]</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I build a function to do this. For the moment i build pseudo code like this:

```
<?php

function generatemydocument ($path_to_content_file,$path_to_template_file,$path_to_output_file){

    if (!file_exists($path_to_xml_file)){
        return;
    }
    if (!file_exists($path_to_template_file)){
        return;
    }
    if (file_exists($path_to_output_file)){
        // make log message output file already exist
        return;
    }

    // read the file into a string
    $templatefile = readfileascompletestring ($path_to_template_file)

    // Search and replace all single dom elemelens with no children

    // Get all elements from dom document with no childs and put it in a array
    // Reallly nu clu how to do this yet ...
    $array_with_strings_to_replace = array("all elements from $path_to_content_file with NO children","all values for this element")

    // init
    $dbData = array(); 
    foreach ($array_with_strings_to_replace as $key => $value)
        $sanitizedValue = strip_tags(ucfirst(strtolower($value)));
        $templatefile = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $sanitizedValue, $templatefile);
        $dbData[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($sanitizedValue);
        // add a line of code into a log file
    }   

    // Search and replace all nodes with the use of a dom translation

    $content = new DOMDocument();
    $content->loadXML($path_to_content_file);

    $template = new DOMDocument();
    $template ->loadHTML($templatefile);

    // Create a new document
    $newdoc = new DOMDocument;
    $newdoc->formatOutput = true;

    // Set the template in the newdoc
    $newdoc = $template

    // Import the node, and all its children, to the document
    $node = $newdoc->importNode($node, true);

    // I think  I have to do some replacements here but I'm a little bit lost in here

    // And then append it to the "<root>" node
    $newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($node);

    $newdoc->saveHTML($path_to_output_file  );

}
?>
```

But the more I understand of this dom library of php I have some questions.

1) Now, I do a string replace action for nodes which have no children nodes. I get the feeling this can be done with DOMNode DOMDocument::importNode and that the importnode just import the node with or without children nodes. Is that correct?

2) I do not understand how to deal with the merging on a node in the content and in the template. Should I do a replace and search for this also?

3) I do not have the idea that this is new in this world. Is there a library function which can do this already?

The function should not contain any information from the dom documents itself, I can change the input variables of the function with information we need to merge this complete thing e.g a list with all names of the elements.

Can this be done more easily?

In the end this should be a module in drupal7 where users are selecting a node in the system (this will give content.xml) and this node will be a downloaded in a word document (template.html is the basis of this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing a template system. Here do exists a lot of template systems. For XML/HTML here is a specific language called XSLT that can be used to transform it.

But you're using your own syntax for the placeholders (not attributes or tags). For XSLT you would need to do something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Opdrachtgever</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td><t:text name="opdrachtgever"/></td>
</tr>
```

Or you use the HTML5 style:

```
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Opdrachtgever</td>
  <td>:</td>
  <td data-template-content="opdrachtgever"></td>
</tr>
```

Elements and attributes can be matched with Xpath 1.0.

- Any element in the specific template namespace: `//t:*`
- Any element with the data attribute: `//*[@data-template-content]`

With the template logic matchable by Xpath you can implement it in PHP using DOM and DOMXpath. `DOMDocument::importNode()` does import and clone a node from a second document. If you're using the DOM methods they will take care of encoding and escaping issues.

Using XSLT will provide you with the necessary template logic like loops and conditions. It can import data from additional XML documents, too.

Comment: thxs, i looked into XSLT and did some testing, I will definitly replace my example "HTML template" with XSLT syntax.